# Get Twitter profile photo

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to create an interface of tweets with a special hashtag , and i want to add a profile photo picture in tweets , is there any way to get the  twitter profile photo using twitter4j ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through the following code.

```
Assume that the Twitter object is mytTwitter
*get the user from the twitter object

User user = mytTwitter.showUser(mytTwitter.getid());

*get the profile image URL

URL url = user.getProfileImageURL();


*create Image icon

ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);

*set the JLabel icon to be the ImageIcon

Jlabel1.setIcon(img);
```

Comment: I'm using android , how can I load imageview from url ?

Comment: for loading image from Url use URLImageViewHelper library, go to following link https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper , download library and write code for image as following  UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(this, holder.imageView, URL, R.drawable.temp_profile_pic_placeholder);

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You must get a status and then:

```
status.getUser().getProfileImageURL(); //returns a string which is profile image url
```

For detailed usage:

[getProfileImageURL()](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/User.html#getProfileImageURL%28%29)

[twitter4j Javadoc](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/index.html)